# RABL OR PLAIN JSON formatting - how do I group results by common key?

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rabl

```
{"controller_id"=>699, "high_temp"=>11, "low_temp"=>8, "date"=>"2014-01-13"}
{"controller_id"=>699, "high_temp"=>11, "low_temp"=>7, "date"=>"2014-01-14"}
{"controller_id"=>699, "high_temp"=>10, "low_temp"=>6, "date"=>"2014-01-15"}
{"controller_id"=>794, "high_temp"=>39, "low_temp"=>34, "date"=>"2014-01-17"}
{"controller_id"=>794, "high_temp"=>77, "low_temp"=>62, "date"=>"2014-01-18"}
{"controller_id"=>794, "high_temp"=>16, "low_temp"=>85, "date"=>"2014-01-19"}
{"controller_id"=>794, "high_temp"=>37, "low_temp"=>47, "date"=>"2014-01-20"}
```

Above is a sample of the output.

These results are coming back from ActiveRecord as Objects.  Example:

```
#<ControllerWeatherDay controller_id: 699, high_temp: 8, low_temp: 0, date: "2014-01-01">
```

As you can see, we report weather for controllers by date, what I'm trying to do in RABL that I have been struggling with is:

```
{"controllers" : [
                   {
                      id:699,
                      weather: [
                                 {"high_temp"=>11, "low_temp"=>8, "date"=>"2014-01-13"},
                                 {"high_temp"=>11, "low_temp"=>7, "date"=>"2014-01-14"},
                                 {"high_temp"=>10, "low_temp"=>6, "date"=>"2014-01-15"}
                                ]
                    },
                    {
                       id:794,
                       weather: [
                                  {"high_temp"=>39, "low_temp"=>34, "date"=>"2014-01-17"},
                                  {"high_temp"=>77, "low_temp"=>62, "date"=>"2014-01-18"},
                                  {"high_temp"=>16, "low_temp"=>85, "date"=>"2014-01-19"},
                                  {"high_temp"=>37, "low_temp"=>47, "date"=>"2014-01-20"}
                                ]
                     }
                 ]
        }
```

I am TOTALLY ok with not using RABL.  It's a pain in the ass.  Regular JSON object construction is ok with me.  Any help is appreciated.

RABL :

```
object @weather

if params[:controller_id]
    attributes :controller_id, :high_temp, :low_temp, :date
else
    attributes :high_temp, :low_temp, :date
end
```

I've worked through various node :high_temp do |h| stuff end iterations, but I'm honestly not thrilled with RABL.  Happy to dump it.

Comment: show your `.rabl` views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution w/out `RABL` (I omit the deletion of `controller_id` from the resulting arrays for the sake of code readness):

```
data = [
  {"controller_id"=>699, "high_temp"=>11, "low_temp"=>8, "date"=>"2014-01-13"},
  {"controller_id"=>699, "high_temp"=>11, "low_temp"=>7, "date"=>"2014-01-14"},
  {"controller_id"=>699, "high_temp"=>10, "low_temp"=>6, "date"=>"2014-01-15"},
  {"controller_id"=>794, "high_temp"=>39, "low_temp"=>34, "date"=>"2014-01-17"},
  {"controller_id"=>794, "high_temp"=>77, "low_temp"=>62, "date"=>"2014-01-18"},
  {"controller_id"=>794, "high_temp"=>16, "low_temp"=>85, "date"=>"2014-01-19"},
  {"controller_id"=>794, "high_temp"=>37, "low_temp"=>47, "date"=>"2014-01-20"}
]

result = data.inject({}) { |memo, c|  # memoize the hash
  (memo["#{c['controller_id']}"] ||= []) << c;  memo 
}.map { |id, weather|                 # map to desired output format
  { :id => id, :weather => weather } 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try out the following code (I presume an array variable called input_data which contains, yeah, the input data :-)):

```
# Make a hash where controller_ids are keys
mid_result = input_data.inject({}) do |res, el| 
  if el["controller_id"] 
    res[el["controller_id"]] ||= [] 
    res[el["controller_id"]].push( el.slice("high_temp", "low_temp", "date")) 
  end

  res 
end

# Final formatting
{
  "controllers" => mid_result.map do |key, value| 
    {"id" => key, "weather" => value}
  end 
}
```

Then you can call `.to_json` on the final result if you need

Comment: It's complaining about slice - these hashes at the top came back from ActiveRecord - so they're objects right now that I have to manipulate.  I'll update my original post with that information.

Comment: I see. You can use ```to_a``` on the array but you will still have AR objects and not hashes so ```slice``` will not work. Since you have your answer already, let's leave it at that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
arr.group_by { |x| x['controller_id'] }.map { |id, weather| {id: id, weather: weather } }
# => [{:id=>699, :weather=>[
#       {"controller_id"=>699, "high_temp"=>11, "low_temp"=>8, "date"=>"2014-01-13"},   
#       {"controller_id"=>699, "high_temp"=>11, "low_temp"=>7, "date"=>"2014-01-14"}, 
#       {"controller_id"=>699, "high_temp"=>10, "low_temp"=>6, "date"=>"2014-01-15"}]}
#     [{:id=>794, :weather=>[
#       {"controller_id"=>794, "high_temp"=>39, "low_temp"=>34, "date"=>"2014-01-17"}, 
#       {"controller_id"=>794, "high_temp"=>77, "low_temp"=>62, "date"=>"2014-01-18"}, 
#       {"controller_id"=>794, "high_temp"=>16, "low_temp"=>85, "date"=>"2014-01-19"}, 
#       {"controller_id"=>794, "high_temp"=>37, "low_temp"=>47, "date"=>"2014-01-20"}]}
#     ]
```